# Trouble Installing ROS on Peppermint 10

Tags: ros

I have installed ROS Melodic on my Peppermint OS. I follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) instruction, when i try rosdep command, i got this error.

```
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Could not detect OS, tried ['windows', 'nixos', 'clearlinux', 'ubuntu', 'slackware', 'rhel', 'qnx', 'osx', 'tizen', 'opensuse', 'opensuse', 'opensuse', 'openembedded', 'neon', 'mx', 'mint', 'linaro', 'gentoo', 'funtoo', 'freebsd', 'fedora', 'elementary', 'elementary', 'debian', 'cygwin', 'centos', 'manjaro', 'arch', 'alpine']
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.17.1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 144, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 426, in _rosdep_main
    return _no_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 435, in _no_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 646, in command_update
    skip_eol_distros=not options.include_eol_distros)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 498, in update_sources_list
    rosdep_data = get_gbprepo_as_rosdep_data(dist_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py", line 150, in get_gbprepo_as_rosdep_data
    ctx = create_default_installer_context()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 90, in create_default_installer_context
    m.register_platforms(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py", line 55, in register_platforms
    register_elementary(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/debian.py", line 82, in register_elementary
    (os_name, os_version) = context.get_os_name_and_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 115, in get_os_name_and_version
    os_name = self.os_detect.get_name()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py", line 685, in get_name
    self.detect_os()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py", line 655, in detect_os
    raise OsNotDetected("Could not detect OS, tried %s" % attempted)
OsNotDetected: Could not detect OS, tried ['windows', 'nixos', 'clearlinux', 'ubuntu', 'slackware', 'rhel', 'qnx', 'osx', 'tizen', 'opensuse', 'opensuse', 'opensuse', 'openembedded', 'neon', 'mx', 'mint', 'linaro', 'gentoo', 'funtoo', 'freebsd', 'fedora', 'elementary', 'elementary', 'debian', 'cygwin', 'centos', 'manjaro', 'arch', 'alpine']
```

Any Solution?
Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the ROS is not supported on Peppermint. The python script /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py tries to detect the current OS type. Since Peppermint OS is based on Ubuntu, you could try overriding the detected OS type by setting the ROS_OS_OVERRIDE env variable. A quick search shows that Peppermint 10 OS is based on Ubuntu 18.04.2 so you could try the following before running the command:

```
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:18.04:bionic
```